# Using ffmpeg to convert video in c++ streaming server

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I can't understand how use libavcodec to convert, for example, from avi to h.264. Can I convert video in my C++ program in this way:

```
file=popen("ffmpeg -i file.avi file.m4v");
```

Can I use this function to dynamically stream without waiting to finish a video converting process?

Comment: If you do not want to wait for the process execution, you had better use `fork` and `exec` family functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can not stream a m4v file while it is being transcoded. ffmpeg writes metadata at the end of the transcoding process which is needed to stream a video. After finished conversion you have to use [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box) or [qt-fatsstart](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/qt-faststart_8c-source.html) to put this metadata at the beginning. If you still want to stream video while conversion going on, I think you have to convert the video to MPEG transport stream (mpeg-ts) format.